# How to change Joomla Articles Navigation links to images

Tags: joomla

Which php page generates the Pre/Next links in articles, when I have enables "Show navigation" in the advanced parameters section for the menu assigned with the Articles of a particular category.
Also how can I replace the Pre/Next button in articles to images?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should not modify the joomla core code directly. To use images just add in the css file something like:

```
.prev{
background-image:url(images/prev.gif);
}
```

Also see this useful extension if it works for you: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/site-navigation/13789

It'll be better to have prev/next page titles than arrow images.

Comment: Thanks... Let me try doing this. Will post the feedback after trying it. Thanks dude.. By the way, how can I replace the Prev/Next buttons with page titles?

Comment: Also it would be nice if someone could tell me which php page in Joomla core generates the Pre/Next links in articles.

Comment: I tried doing what you said, it didn't seem to work. Also I don't see any 'prev' class assigned to the Prev/Next button, then how can it work? DO i need to enable some other option in the Joomla admin menu for this to happen. If so please tell that too.

Comment: The plugin you had said about is awesome and true to its name, it does a good work in replacing the page navigation buttons with the article titles.

Comment: @saji89, in Joomla 3.x, the plugin file is .../plugins/content/pagenavigation/tmpl/default.php